# HTTPS routing in Laravel web app deployed in Azure

Tags: php, laravel, azure, https, web-config

I want to force routing through the HTTPS. I have a web application in the Azure cloud platform with the following web.config file in the /public folder:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In order to force the routing, Azure [says](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/01/07/https-only-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) to add this:

```
<system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
      <rules>
         <rule name=”Redirect to https”>
            <match url=”(.*)”/>
            <conditions>
                <add input=”{HTTPS}” pattern=”Off”/>
                <add input=”{REQUEST_METHOD}” pattern=”^get$|^head$” />
            </conditions>
            <action type=”Redirect” url=”https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}”/>
         </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Do you have any idea on how can I change my original web.config file so that it fits and forces HTTPS?

**SOLVED**

I just had to add the rule. The modified web config is:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
          <rule name=”Redirect to https”>
            <match url=”(.*)”/>
            <conditions>
                <add input=”{HTTPS}” pattern=”Off”/>
                <add input=”{REQUEST_METHOD}” pattern=”^get$|^head$” />
            </conditions>
            <action type=”Redirect” url=”https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}”/>
         </rule>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can tackle this problem from the Laravel side.

Consider the following route:

```
Route::get('signin', ['uses' => 'AuthController@signin', 'https']);
```

This route will only be served as https. I had to deal with this situation some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

If your laravel application's directory architecture is like:

```
wwwroot/
    app/
    public/
    ...
    .env
    ...
```

You can directly create a file `web.config` with the content in the root directory in your application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
      <rules>
         <rule name="Redirect to https">
            <match url="(.*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/public/{R:1}"/>
         </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Which will redirect all the HTTP requests to HTTPS, and redirect to the into the public folder.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.